# Bash shell how do i format Date to be lower case for month?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

The following command makes the date Sept18_1024x728.jpg how do i make it so it will format it with sept18_1024x728.jpg instead?

```
           cp "$p" "./FOLDER/$(date +%b%d).$SIZE.jpg"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pipe through `tr` to translate upper to lowercase:

```
cp "$p" "./FOLDER/$(date +%b%d | tr A-Z a-z).$SIZE.jpg"
```

Or the locale-aware version:

```
cp "$p" "./FOLDER/$(date +%b%d | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]').$SIZE.jpg"
```

Answer (score 1):

`bash` to lower case function...

```
$ d=$(date +%b%d); cp "$p" "./FOLDER/${d,,}.$SIZE.jpg"
```

NB. in this particular case `${d,}` will also work, since only the first char needs to be converted.

Comment: what version of `bash` are you using?  I don't know when this was introduced. I have version 4.3.42

Comment: im using macs automator to make scripts. i tried using ('s but still have no luck.

Comment: @karakfa: they were introduced in v4.0; OS X comes with v3. something. Here's a useful link: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/061

Comment: @Likenota Please, note that `d` in `${d,,}` needs to be a parameter or variable. Directly placing the output of a `$()` command would indeed result in a `bad substitution error`. Here is the [official GNU shell parameter expansion documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).